# Cannot resolve icu4j

Tags: java, maven, icu4j

In my pom.xml I have many dependencies, but one is not resolved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>70.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Producing the error:

> Cannot resolve com.ibm.icu:icu4j:70.1

I've checked and icu4j version 70.1 exists on maven.

I've tried to refresh the maven and also to rebuild, but no help.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe your looking up the wrong maven repos. Maybe you are also behind a proxy. Hard to guess without seeing all the info and your setup. Voting to close as its missing debugging details.

Comment: The identical dependency worked for me. You must be behind a proxy (Nexus?) or have a problem with your Maven configuration.

Comment: Have you tried running maven with the "-X" option to produce more output?

Comment: If you can see the artifacts online, maybe download them manually to your local Maven repository.